# AzureAD/OIDC authentication differences in .Net Framework and .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I'm trying to use AzureAD authentication in a ASP.Net Core application and making some controller actions not require user to login.

Using Visual Studio 2019, if I create a brand new ASP.Net Framework application and select Work/School accounts for authentication - the HomeController is decorated with the Authorize attribute. As soon as I run the application, I'm redirected to the Azure login screen. If I move the Authorize attribute from the top of the Home controller to the Contact action, when I run the application I'm not redirected to login until I click the Contact link. This is exactly what I'd expect.

If I create a brand new ASP.Net Core application (again selecting Work/School accounts for authentication)- and move the Authorize attribute from the top of the Home controller to the Privacy action - I'm redirected to login as soon as I run the application, instead of waiting for me to navigate to the Privacy action.

**Code sample**

This

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
...
public IActionResult Privacy()
...
```

behaves the same as this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
...
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Privacy()
...
```

in ASP.Net Core.

1) What's different about the authentication between these two?
2) Is there an easy way to make the ASP.Net Core application only authenticate when hitting an Authorize attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because asp.net core template create a global `AuthorizeFilter` to make sure all actions require authenticated user to access :

.NET Core 2.x :

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
```

.Net Core 3.x:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

You can just delete the filter :

.NET Core 2.x :

```
services.AddMvc()
```

.NET Core 3.x :

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```